# Uso della congiunzione "mentre" con valore avversativo

Tags: grammar, word-usage, conjunctions

Mi sento insicura sull'uso della congiunzione "*mentre*" con valore avversativo. A volte non so se sia meglio usare "*invece*" o "*mentre*", oppure non so se debba scrivere "*mentre*" oppure "*mentre che*". Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Ad esempio, cosa si dovrebbe usare per completare queste frasi? "*Mentre*"? "*Mentre che*"? "*Invece*"?

- Giovanni studia molto, _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ tu non fai niente.
- L'antipasto era molto buono, _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ la pasta era un po' salata.
- In catalano, l'accento sulla "*a*" è sempre grave, sulla "*i*" e sulla "*u*" è sempre acuto, _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ sulla "*e*" e sulla "*o*" può essere grave o acuto.
- Il governo esige tagli alla spesa, _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ i sindacati chiedono aumenti salariali.
- La Patagonia è una delle regioni con la temperatura più diversa del pianeta. Fino ad una estremità [?] potete viaggiare attraverso dei bellissimi fiordi e ghiacciai, _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ in altri percorsi potete andare attraverso campi pieni di fiori silvestri.

L'ultimo esempio l'ho tratto da [Internet](http://www.australis.com/site/ita/blog/che-cose-dovete-mettere-in-valigia-per-la-vostra-crociera-alla-patagonia/), ma non sono sicura che sia del tutto corretto (mi sa che è una cattiva traduzione).

Comment: Puoi fare degli esempi? _Invece_ non è una congiunzione ma un avverbio, giusto?

Comment: Cerco di fare alcuni esempi.

Comment: Sì, l'ultimo esempio non è in italiano, ma in GoogleTranslatese o simili. Per esempio, usa “diversa” come se significasse “varia, eterogenea”, e anche tutto il resto suona alieno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La differenza principale tra *mentre* e *invece* è che la prima è una congiunzione mentre il secondo è un avverbio. Gli esempi che proponi possono risolversi usando indifferentemente l'una o l'altro con l'accortezza di usare il punto e virgola nel secondo caso. Puoi persino fondere [insieme i due elementi](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/sulluso-invece) con uso rafforzativo (benché, come spesso accade nella lingua italiana, l'interlocutore potrebbe avere in ubbia quest'ultima opzione e storcere il naso).

> 1a. Giovanni studia molto, **mentre** tu non fai niente.
>
> 1b. Giovanni studia molto; **invece** tu non fai niente.
>
> 1c. Giovanni studia molto **mentre invece** tu non fai niente.
>
> 2a. L'antipasto era molto buono, **mentre** la pasta era un po' salata.
>
> 2b. L'antipasto era molto buono; **invece** la pasta era un po' salata.
>
> 2c. L'antipasto era molto buono **mentre invece** la pasta era un po' salata.
>
> 3a. In catalano, l'accento sulla "*a*" è sempre grave, sulla "*i*" e sulla "*u*" è sempre acuto, **mentre** sulla "*e*" e sulla "*o*" può essere sia grave che acuto.
>
> 3b. In catalano, l'accento sulla "*a*" è sempre grave; sulla "*i*" e sulla "*u*" è sempre acuto; **invece** sulla "*e*" e sulla "*o*" può essere sia grave che acuto.
>
> 3c. In catalano, l'accento sulla "*a*" è sempre grave, sulla "*i*" e sulla "*u*" è sempre acuto, **mentre invece** sulla "*e*" e sulla "*o*" può essere sia grave che acuto.
>
> 4a. Il governo esige tagli alla spesa, **mentre** i sindacati chiedono aumenti salariali.
>
> 4b. Il governo esige tagli alla spesa; **invece** i sindacati chiedono aumenti salariali.
>
> 4c. Il governo esige tagli alla spesa, **mentre invece** i sindacati chiedono aumenti salariali.
>
> 5a. La Patagonia è una delle regioni con la temperatura più disomogenea del pianeta. Fino ad una estremità [?] potete viaggiare attraverso dei bellissimi fiordi e ghiacciai, **mentre** in altri percorsi potete andare attraverso campi pieni di fiori silvestri.
>
> 5b. La Patagonia è una delle regioni con la temperatura più disomogenea del pianeta. Fino ad una estremità [?] potete viaggiare attraverso dei bellissimi fiordi e ghiacciai; **invece** in altri percorsi potete andare attraverso campi pieni di fiori silvestri.
>
> 5c. La Patagonia è una delle regioni con la temperatura più disomogenea del pianeta. Fino ad una estremità [?] potete viaggiare attraverso dei bellissimi fiordi e ghiacciai, **mentre invece** in altri percorsi potete andare attraverso campi pieni di fiori silvestri.

È chiaro che *mentre*, che viene dal latino *dŭm ĭntĕrim*, ti offre una sfumatura di simultaneità temporale che non è garantita da *invece*. Nota anche che *mentre che* è ormai raro, benché sia presente in italiano sin da Dante e almeno fino agli autori del Novecento.

Comment: Segnalo anche questo [intervento autorevole](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/possibilit).